# Error while accessing SVN Repository

Tags: windows, configuration, android, svn

we are working on one android project in our company using Eclipse as an IDE.
one person is works on windows platform while i am using ubuntu for android development.
we need to connect same project via svn repository.

Now the problem is we couldn't connect our server via Ubuntu.
I recently started ubuntu for development so i really don't know much more things about Ubuntu.
so we failed to connect our project via svn repository. Repository is windows based.

So how do I configure SVN repository in Ubuntu? How to connect server from Ubuntu?(server is on windows platform)

How to communicate between Windows and Ubuntu?

While checkout our project it gives some error.
I posted error below. please have look on this

Checkout operation for 'file://serversystem/application_directory/Android' failed.
svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file://serversystem/application_directory/Android'
svn: E170000: Local URL 'file://serversystem/application_directory/Android' contains unsupported hostname

I checked all the possibilities like  svn://,    file:///,  http://;   but we failed to access repository

Thanks and regards
tj

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you must to know, that you want to have and that to do in order to reach results. Now you are far away from this state

> android project in our company using Eclipse as an IDE

Irrelevant to task

> one person is works on windows platform while i am using ubuntu

Irrelevant to task

---

> we need to connect same project via svn repository.

and

> Now the problem is we couldn't connect our server via Ubuntu.

pair *drive me nuts* !!!.

Your task **really is** "Organize Sorce Control  in Subversion for at least 2 separate Workspaces of developers"

In order to to it and because Subversion is CVCS, you have to build Subversion-server (on *any* available platform), create at least one repository and define (if needed) ACL for repo-access. As results

Users perform development in own Working Copies, store results in Repository, which can be accessed any of existing (and enabled) methods. //serversystem/application_directory/Android now is not a repository, I suppose. Read [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html), chapters 5 and 6 at least